# Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse

estou com um problema em uma query, é um trabalho da faculdade, uma criação de um DataWare House. Bom, eu preciso inserir na minha tabela principal (f_contrato), algumas informações, as mesmas estão em outras tabelas e eu preciso buscar dessas tabelas as informações para a inserção na tabela f_contrato. A query para a inserção no momento é esta:

```
    (SELECT 
    I.CD_IMO,
    F.CD_FUN,
    I.NR_CEP,

    (SELECT 
            NR_MES,
                NR_ANO,
                (SELECT 
                        SUM(VL_PAR)
                    FROM
                        PARCELA
                    WHERE
                        YEAR(DT_VCTO) = NR_ANO
                            AND MONTH(DT_VCTO) = NR_MES
                            AND DT_PAGTO IS NULL
                    GROUP BY NR_ANO , NR_MES) TOT_REC,
                (SELECT 
                        SUM(VL_PAR)
                    FROM
                        PARCELA
                    WHERE
                        YEAR(DT_PAGTO) = NR_ANO
                            AND MONTH(DT_PAGTO) = NR_MES
                            AND DT_PAGTO IS NOT NULL
                    GROUP BY NR_ANO , NR_MES) TOT_PAGO
        FROM
            D_TEMPO)
FROM
    FUNCIONARIO F,
    CONTRATO C,
    IMOVEL I,
    LOGRADOURO L
WHERE
    I.CD_IMO = C.CD_IMO
        AND I.NR_CEP = L.NR_CEP
        AND F.CD_FUN = C.CD_FUN
        AND PARCELA.CD_CON = C.CD_CON);
```

---

Eu havia feito alguns testes com algumas querys de select:
Por exemplo, nesse select eu retorno o valor das parcelas que estão pagas e o total das parcelas que estão em aberto utilizando subselect e o sum:

```
SELECT 
    NR_MES,
    NR_ANO,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(VL_PAR) TOT_PAGO
        FROM
            PARCELA
        WHERE
            YEAR(DT_VCTO) = NR_ANO
                AND MONTH(DT_VCTO) = NR_MES
                AND DT_PAGTO IS NULL
        GROUP BY NR_ANO , NR_MES) TOT_REC,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(VL_PAR) TOT_PAGO
        FROM
            PARCELA
        WHERE
            YEAR(DT_PAGTO) = NR_ANO
                AND MONTH(DT_PAGTO) = NR_MES
                AND DT_PAGTO IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY NR_ANO , NR_MES) TOT_PAGO
FROM
    D_TEMPO
```

---

### O Retorno dessa query com o sum é este aqui:[image: Valor total das parcelas abertas e pagas agrupadas por ano e mês, estão com o mesmo valor pois populei o banco sempre com a mesma informação]

[image: Campos da tabela f_contrato]

---

Basicamente, eu preciso juntar 2 query para fazer a inserção de todos os dados na tabela f_contrato, a query da soma das parcelas agrupada por ano e mês e essa última.

```
(SELECT 
    I.CD_IMO, F.CD_FUN, I.NR_CEP
FROM
    FUNCIONARIO F,
    CONTRATO C,
    IMOVEL I,
    LOGRADOURO L
WHERE
    I.CD_IMO = C.CD_IMO
        AND I.NR_CEP = L.NR_CEP
        AND F.CD_FUN = C.CD_FUN);
```

---

[image: Essa query me retorna os dados do imovel, funcionário, e cep do imovel]